# How to specify the directory of archive to be extracted using jar command?

Tags: java, shell, command-line, jar

I have

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\jar.exe

D:\ounce\advanced\bank.zip
```

Currently, my command shell is at

```
D:\ounce\advanced>
```

When I use this command:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\jar xf D:\ounce\advanced\bank.zip
```

to extract bank.zip, I get "illegal option: F" The same thing happens when I replace  D:\ounce\advanced\bank.zip with just bank.zip

I'm trying to do it the hard way without using environment variables.
How can I do this right?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

program files - has space in it

you need to put the entire path in double quotes

Comment: Thank you very much, my savior. I did try put double quotes around Program Files but never thought of doing that for the entire path. Oh my.. searching and experimenting around for hours.